# Proof Involving Affine Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L be a subspace of $R^n$. Suppose **a** is in $R^n$ and let L'=**a**+L.
Prove that if **v** is any vector in L' and **x** is any vector in L, then **v+x** is in L'.

I'm not really sure where to start. Thanks

Comment: well, what are the elements of $L'$?

Comment: It would include all of the vectors in L added to a right?

Comment: yes, and so..  $ $